# how to rate popularity of person across the world?

Tags: php, algorithm, artificial-intelligence, search-engine, web-crawler

i want to made one application that measure popularity of person across the world.
Is there any algorithm for that like google's page rank algorithm
if not then how can i make it ?

i have to get popularity of today , not past some dayz.

Please reopen my question because this is original and  quite interesting for all...

Comment: Yep: http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?word1=Steve+Jobs&word2=Mark+Zuckerberg

Comment: You have to explain what you mean by popularity, what criteria you will use to define it, ...

Comment: you wont be popular here asking such terrible questions.

Comment: hmm.. hey guys. lets say i want to check who is more popular among this five celebrity. so that i can show that best three out of this five based on there popularity. lets say this five names are "brad pitt", "will smith", "bruce willis", "enrique iglesias", "eminem" ??

Comment: You can turn this into a programming question, maybe ask it over at programmers and give some ideas for an index.

Comment: @MikeB : yup i'm explaining you question..

Comment: very simple method could be most hits on google in last month

Comment: Guys if you can't help than please don't close the question also..!!

Comment: closing this question is "democracy in the form of dictatorship" , very bad :(  Guys you closed this question in 15 minutes . 15 minutes is very less time to sort out an AI algo .Think again plz.

Comment: In that perspective @MikeB you are right not a word from him yet !

Comment: @MikeB  .popularity is the term that say all thing what i want to do..i have to  compare popularity between some set pf person. and finding most popular person

Comment: @aioobe yes i want like this but how can i implement programmatically that y thi s question is in stackoverflow

Comment: @Dagon how can i get hits from google? is there any api for that?

Comment: dont know why people close this interesting artificial intelligence question..please reopen it...

Comment: @sakhunzai  i m sorry for not responding that time ..but in india this is a late night..

Comment: @MikeB : Its my question also. the clarification i had provided is not assumption.. that is the real situation.. and we want to find solution for that. we care of your time. but its not possible to reply immediately. so please request you to reopen it.

Comment: and its interesting and challenging task.. so please provide help if you can..

Comment: poorly asked question that's why it was closed, failed to define what criteria make popularity, you would be better off asking again with sufficient thought given to the actual question.

Comment: that made no sense in English.

Comment: @dagon. : hey mate... if you have any tips about how can i improve my question so that everyone can understand than please let me know.. i would like to ask it again.

Answer (score 2):

Very interesting question ,I don't have knowledge of such algorithm but  I can guess some variable :

Let say X is person 
a) How X is affecting our lives e.g
   politics, ecnomics ,science ....

1. Did a very good job :)
2. Did a very bad job :(
3. Did a unique job ....

b) Number of people directly affected by

c) Duration/Period (very short , during his life time , one might be popular in old age , one might be at very young age)
   e.g a teen inventing sth new or doing sth extra ordinary or at very young age

d) We need to define popularity ( consult a social scientist :)

hope this might be helpful , looking forward for other responses :)

Edit: How to measure the variables

```
a) Develop an intelligent webbot to cram the variables in question
   (Don't ask me how)
  Check someone has already developed an algo to determine the THREAT level
  world wide :)

b) possible sources 
   Forums, News, Chatrooms , IRC,Google Search Trends  .......
```

Comment: for more check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394017/what-are-some-impressive-algorithms-or-software-in-the-world-of-ai